# Cómo crear un evento en javascript para crear una imagen y cambiarla por un texto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un programa en Javascript que crea imagenes a traves de una entrada en un input y quiero introducir un texto en dicha imagen o mas bien cambiar la imagen por texto. Tengo el siguiente código que con un `input` separa la frase por el carácter espacio y luego crea una imagen por cada letra, quería insertar un texto al pulsar sobre la imagen creada con CreateElement(img). Importante pulsar sobre la imagen creada

Tengo varias pruebas hechas y no lo consigo.

**Así funciona:**

1. Tengo una variable *contenido* que recoge la frase y la separa por el caracter espacio,
2. luego recorro el array y creo arreglos con cada palabra,
3. me crea una variable *imagen* que crea un elemento imagen,
4. inserto la imagen llamada *R*, le doy un `id` a la imagen,
5. inserto la imagen dentro (este paso no sé por qué pero si no no funciona),
6. luego uso jquery intentando que funcione el evento.
7. Se puede usar un div y añadir la imagen con un url desde css pero como hago si el div es invisible porque esta creado para asociarle un acción, si creo un div solo se puede pulsar si es diferente porque esta el id en html.
8. Se le puede asociar un id y lo tengo que asociar de forma diferente al que uso en html
9. Se puede insertar un elemento creado sobre un id en html ya creado? algun ejemplo porfavor
10. La variable que tiene de nombre *idColor* (esta asociada a un id es decir eso debe de estar bien según las reglas que hya por internet, la imagen creada porque está asociada a un id)
    La puedo asociar a un id, pero la pregunta tambien seria se puede usar ese valor de algún modo para hacer que se use con el getElementById ese id, puede ser asociado a una accion, porque no consigo hacerlo

Alguna solución creativa o diferente?. Algun codigo para usar?

```
function imagen() {
    var contenido = document.getElementById('palabra').value.toUpperCase();
    let arr = contenido.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "R.jpg";
        var idColor = "bloque0" + i;
        img.id = idColor;
        var src = document.getElementById("bloque0" + i);
        document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
        var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[0][i]);
        $("#idColor").click(function() {
            var nombre = $("newContent").val();
            $("#idColor").html(nombre);
        });
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr[1].length; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "R.jpg";
        var idColor = "bloque1" + i;
        img.id = idColor;
        var src = document.getElementById("bloque1" + i);
        document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
        var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[1][i]);
        var currentDiv = document.getElementById("bloque1" + i);
        document.body.insertBefore(newContent, currentDiv);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr[2].length; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "R.jpg";
        var idColor = 'bloque0' + i;
        img.id = idColor;
        var src = document.getElementById("bloque2" + i);
        document.body.insertBefore(img, src);
        var newContent = document.createTextNode(arr[2][i]);
        var currentDiv = document.getElementById("bloque2" + i);
        document.body.insertBefore(newContent, currentDiv);
    }
}
```